# Is this sentence of Vitalik Buterin correct?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, commas, present-tense, present-continuous

I was reading [*A Philosophy of Blockchain Validation*](https://vitalik.ca/general/2020/08/17/philosophy.html) of [Vitalik Buterin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitalik_Buterin). The following sentence strikes me as odd:

> Data availability checks do rely on a very conservative assumption that there exists at least some small number of honest nodes somewhere in the network **continues to apply**, though the good news is that this minimum honesty threshold is low, and does not grow even if there is a very large number of attackers.

I would humbly restate the sentence in the following manner:

> Data availability checks do rely on a very conservative assumption continuing to apply, namely that there exists at least some small number of honest nodes somewhere in the network, though the good news is that this minimum honesty threshold is low, and does not grow even if there is a very large number of attackers.

or would make it even more concise:

> Data availability checks do rely on a very conservative assumption that there exists at least some small number of honest nodes somewhere in the network, though the good news is that this minimum honesty threshold is low, and does not grow even if there is a very large number of attackers.

Is Buterin's sentence correct? If not, what is not correct in it? Do my attempts of correcting the sentence make sense to y'all?

P.S. This is not a proofreading request. The relevant text was published five weeks prior to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buterin’s original is incorrect. “... *network applies* ...” should say “... *network that applies* ...”, with “*that*” referring to the previously mentioned *assumption*.

Your final version seems the best. It removes the redundant and unnecessary “*continues to apply*”, which adds nothing to the stated reliance on an existing assumption.

The only modification I suggest is to remove *“do”*, which is not needed. Its only function is to place a little emphasis on the reliance, and I doubt that that emphasis is needed.

Comment: Would you insert then “... network that applies ...” without any punctuation? Like so, "Data availability checks do rely on a very conservative assumption that there exists at least some small number of honest nodes somewhere in the network that continues to apply, [...]"? Such sentence remains ambiguous. One could think that ***that*** applies to ***some small number of honest nodes*** and not to the assumption itself.

Comment: If altered as in your comment, two extra commas would make it grammatically correct and remove the hint of ambiguity by putting the clause into clear apposition with *assumption*: "*Data availability checks do rely on a very conservative assumption, that there exists at least some small number of honest nodes somewhere in the network, that continues to apply ...*". I see there are two votes to close your question - probably because to some people it looks like a proofreading request. I did not regard it as such.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the matter of proofreading - I already modified my question.